# How to recursively fill a tree with 4 children below each node in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, minimax

I've built my own tree data class in Java which is to be used in a minimax algorithm. Each node in the tree will hold a Board object (something else I created) representing a unique game state, and edges (Integer's representing move directions —— the game is Tron) in the tree will represent the move made by a user to reach the state the edge leads to. I want to make a function which takes in a Tree and recursively fills it up to a depth 'DEPTH' (held as a constant elsewhere, not a parameter) with modified game states given each of the four possible Integer moves made by each player at each level. I'm just not quite sure how best to do it...

Also, since it's being used for minimax, the tree structure has to be as follows:

- A root representing the current, unchanged game state
- 1st level children representing the altered game states given the user's 4 possible moves
- 2nd level children representing the altered game states given the opponent's 4 possible moves
- 3rd level game states for the user's 4 moves given the opponent's moves, and so on... extending on to DEPTH number of levels

Here are the basic methods that I have to work with:

- a constructor for Tree taking a Board and an Integer direction leading to the board
- a method called produceChildren() that takes a Tree and boolean 'userMove' and adds 4 new Board's to the Tree's internal list of children which represent the altered game states given each of the user or opponent's 4 possible moves. The 'userMove' parameter designates whether the Board's produced as children should be results of a user's 4 moves or an opponent's 4 moves.
- a method of Tree called getDepth() that return the node's depth within a larger tree consisting of its parent and children (if it has any) --> returns 0 if it is the root

Could anyone perhaps provide me with a bit of pseudocode (using the methods I've provided, unless other methods are needed) for how I would fill a Tree in this alternating, minimax-catered way?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of comments on your data structure before you move on to implementation of the logic.

It's not necessary to store a complete copy of the board in each node of the tree. Given it's being used for minimax the only thing you need to know at each point is the moves to get there and the value of that position. You will need to know the state of the board in the leaves to calculate the value but even then there's no need to keep a copy of it once the calculation is complete.

To go even further, minimax doesn't even require you to keep a permanent copy of the tree. If done using recursion the max or min value at each node can be kept in local variables and returned - there's no need to keep a permanent copy in a tree.

The wikipedia article on [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) has some pseudocode that can get you started.